# Problem Creating Instances of ASP.NET User Controls Programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net-3.5

I am able to create controls pro grammatically using the code below without issue:

```
FileListReader fReader = (FileListReader)LoadControl("~/Controls/FileListReader.ascx");
phFileLists.Controls.Add(fReader);
```

However, I would like to change the control so that I can give it a constructor like this:

```
public FileListReader(Int32 itemGroupId, Int32 documentType, String HeaderString, String FooterString, bool isAdminUser)
{
    base.Construct();
    this.itemGroupId = itemGroupId;
    this.documentType = documentType;
    this.HeaderString = HeaderString;
    this.FooterString = FooterString;
    this.isAdminUser = isAdminUser;
}
```

and then I should be able to call the control like this:

```
FileListReader fReader = (FileListReader)LoadControl(typeof(FileListReader), new Object[] { itemGroupId, 6, "Sell Sheets", "<br /><br />", isAdminUser });
```

However, when I do this I always get an error that my in page controls within my FileListReader Control have not been instantiated and I get a null reference error.  So for example I have an `<asp:Label></asp:label>` control that errors out when I try to set it's text on the Page_Load method.  What is causing this?  I figured the `base.Construct()` would have solved this issue but it obviously has not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to inherit a constructor is like this:

```
class FileListReader : WebControl
{
public FileListReader(Int32 itemGroupId, 
                          Int32 documentType, 
                          String HeaderString, 
                          String FooterString, 
                          bool isAdminUser) : base()  // <-- notice the inherit
{

    this.itemGroupId = itemGroupId;
    this.documentType = documentType;
    this.HeaderString = HeaderString;
    this.FooterString = FooterString;
    this.isAdminUser = isAdminUser;
}
  // ... other code here ... //
}
```

Does changing your constructor like that fix the issue?

Comment: I still get an error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` for the same reason, even with the :base()

Comment: your first code snippet, where you create and add the control... what method are you doing that in?

Comment: I am doing it from `Page_Load`

Comment: Also, my class is `public partial class FileListReader : System.Web.UI.UserControl`.  I don't know if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that calling `base.Contruct()` is what you should be doing, try calling the default contructor of the base class example below:

```
public FileListReader(Int32 itemGroupId, Int32 documentType, String HeaderString, String FooterString, bool isAdminUser) :base()
{
    base.Construct();
    this.itemGroupId = itemGroupId;
    this.documentType = documentType;
    this.HeaderString = HeaderString;
    this.FooterString = FooterString;
    this.isAdminUser = isAdminUser;
}
```

Comment: I still get an error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` for the same reason, even with the :base()